# Can I download a game from EU E-shop on the Wii U whilst in Australia?

Tags: wii-u, region-lock

I don't have a Wii U yet but am after a specific game (underground), only available on EU E-shop, but I live in Australia.
Is there a way to buy Wii U here, then connect to EU E-shop, download the game and go back to AUS E-shop? If not through console itself, can i use a vpn?
Or just set the region initially on Europe, then download that game, then change it to Australia? Do you pay with credit card?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't switch the E-shop region.

If you want to play this EU game, you got to buy an EU Wii U because the E-shop connection is linked to the console's region lock.

You might be able to bypass that by hacking the console ... but that's a whole different subject.